# SharePoint people editor not displaying users

Tags: 2010, people-picker, sharepoint-server

I have one requirement in which I have to display the saved users to the share point people editor control. For this I am saving the user names to People/Group column. And i am using the following code for taking theis user to people editor control.

```
SetPeopleEditor(item, Constants.FieldNames.IT_DIRECTOR, pe_ITDirector, oWeb);
```

The definition of the aboe method is shown below.

```
private PickerEntity SetPeopleEditor(SPListItem item, string columnName, PeopleEditor peopleEditor, SPWeb web)
{
    ArrayList entityArrayList = new ArrayList();
    PickerEntity entity = null;
    if (item[columnName] != null)
    {
        char[] to_splitter = { ';' };
        string to_list = item[columnName].ToString(); // Reads value stored in SPList. (i.e., "Domain\User1; Domain\User2")
        string[] arr = to_list.Split(to_splitter);
        string user = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i % 2) != 0)
            {
                user = arr[i].Substring(arr[i].IndexOf("#") + 1);
                entity = new PickerEntity();
                entity.Key = user;
                entity.IsResolved = true;
                entity = peopleEditor.ValidateEntity(entity);
                entityArrayList.Add(entity);
            }
        }


    }
    return entity;
}
```

But unfortunately the control always showing empty value. How can I achieve this by populating data to the people editor control

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. Where you able to resolve the issue and if yes how

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this link:
It should answer your question:
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-get-and-set-the-value-of-a-people-editor-control-programatically-in-SharePoint--960.php